# Python's for loops

Tags: python

Pyhton is new to me and i'm having a little problem with the for loops,
Im used to for loop in java where you can set integers as you like in the loops but can't get it right in python.
the task i was given is to make a function that return True of False.
the function get 3 integers: short rope amount, long rope amount and wanted.
it's known the short rope length is 1 meter and the long rope length is 5 meters.
if the wanted length is in range of the possible lengths of the ropes the function will return True, else false,
for example, 1 short rope and 2 long ropes can get you the following length: [1, 5, 6, 10, 11] and if the wanted length that the function got is in this list of lengths it should return True.
here is my code:

```
def wantedLength(short_amount, long_amount, wanted_length):
    short_rope_length = 1
    long_rope_length = 5
    for i in range(short_amount + 1):
        for j in range(long_amount + 1):
            my_length = [short_rope_length * i + long_rope_length * j, ", "]
    if wanted_length in my_length:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

but when I run the code I get the following error:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

what am I doing wrong in the for loop statement?
thanks in advance!

I tried to change the for loops with other commands like [short_amount] and etc

the traceback as requsted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\barva\PycharmProjects\Giraffe\Ariel-Exc\Exc_2.py", line 89, in <module>
    print(wantedLength(a,b,c))
  File "C:\Users\barva\PycharmProjects\Giraffe\Ariel-Exc\Exc_2.py", line 73, in wantedLength
    if wanted_length in my_length:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: Show us the entire error traceback.  Otherwise we are just guessing where that error is.

Comment: `for <name> in range(...)` cannot give that error. The only other point where you have ` ...in` is at `wanted_length in my_length` but `my_length` would be a list here. Conclusion: either the error is not really what you are describing or this is not really the code you are running.

Comment: The `my_length` array is always of size one, as you do not append to it. Is it supposed to be this way?

Comment: @JohnGordon How do I print here a screen shot?

Comment: @nilsf But it's still a list, and is iterable, so that wouldn't explain the error.

Comment: Do not post the traceback as a screenshot.  Edit your question (click the edit link) and post it there, as plain text.

Comment: Why are you including a comma and space as an element in your list?

Comment: I don't see any way this code could produce that error.  Are you **absolutely sure** that the posted code for the `wantedLength()` function is correct?

Comment: For future reference, when posting, try for a fully running script that demonstrates the problem. For instance, here there should be a call to the function with some integer parameters. As noted, the code you posted isn't the code that generated the error, leading to confusion.

Comment: @tdelaney
I did try to run it with given integers by the user, anyway I will know better for next time 
in addition, can you please explain me why I did get this error? so I'll know for next time? thanks!

Comment: That's a challenge. Your code shows that `my_length` is a list, but the error says `my_length` is an integer. That can't happen. I think that your example is different than what you ran. That's okay - we like shorter examples here. But if you had added a call to your function and run the example before posting, you'd have realized there was a problem. As stands, all we know is that there is a bug in code not shown. Not much we can say there!

Comment: Don't write "solved" into the question  Looks like you consider this solved by an answer, so instead accept that answer.

Comment: @tdelaney
the example is the code I ran but after a little adjustments that Caldazar suggested
the code is working
but you guys help me alot

Comment: @KellyBundy what do you mean? 
I write solved because I got my answer, my meaning was the the problem is solved so others don't waste their time in figuring it out.
it's my first post on this website so excuse me if I don't understand

Comment: I know, but the proper way to signal that is by accepting the answer.

Comment: I'd like to duplicate the problem on my side. Can you tell us the function parameters used to generate the error?

Answer (score -1):

The code you posted could not give you that error. On the other hand, the problem you have with the code is that in each iteration you create a new list with the current value (integer) and a string ",". You need to append values to the list:

```
def wantedLength(short_amount, long_amount, wanted_length):
    short_rope_length = 1
    long_rope_length = 5
    my_length = list()
    for i in range(short_amount + 1):
        for j in range(long_amount + 1):
            my_length.append(short_rope_length * i + long_rope_length * j)
    if wanted_length in my_length:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: thank you mate! 
The code is working and running as it should! 
thanks for the feedback and the help

Answer (score -1):

So, the thing is that you were assigning only the last item to length. If what you want is a array of all the possibilities, you can do something like:

```py
def wantedLength(short_amount, long_amount, wanted_length):
    short_rope_length = 1
    long_rope_length = 5
    my_length=[]
    for i in range(short_amount + 1):
        for j in range(long_amount + 1):
            my_length.append(short_rope_length * i + long_rope_length * j)
    my_length.remove(0)
    my_length.sort()
    if wanted_length in my_length:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: thanks for your time! 
Can I ask why did you sorted the list? 
I can understand why you removed 0 from the list but why the sorting?

Comment: Was just for you to see that the answer  was the same array that your expected output. It should work normally without.